# How to send notification at a specific time and date (firebase cloud messaging)

Tags: node.js, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have successfully implemented Notification in my app using firebase cloud messaging and was able to send notification in my API in the node server using this
`admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, message, notify_options);`

My Question is there a way to schedule this at a specific time and date, for example on Dec 25 on christmas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schedule a notification at a specific time and date using firebase cloud messaging in NodeJs server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69595065/schedule-a-notification-at-a-specific-time-and-date-using-firebase-cloud-messagi)