# Schedule a notification at a specific time and date using firebase cloud messaging in NodeJs server

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have successfully implemented Notification in my app using firebase cloud messaging and was able to send notification in my API in the node server using this `admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, message, notify_options)`

My Question is there a way to schedule this at a specific time and date, for example on Dec 25 on christmas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to schedule this at a specific time and date

Yes, you can use a [scheduled Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions). Since Cloud Functions for Firebase use the Node.js Admin SDK, it's just a matter of reusing your Nodes.js code.

You'll need to save the users `registrationToken`s in a storage that the Cloud Function can read: we usually use Firestore for that.

There is an [example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/d76ea0b36a9d3e8c0c54c271c5ff9ddf47c88894/fcm-notifications) in the Cloud Function Sample Library.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using a paid service such as Google's Firebase functions?

Comment: Hi, activating Cloud Functions indeed requires entering the details of a credit card but there is a **huge** free tier which allows up to 2M invocations/month for free.  You'll be only billed for each container required to deploy a function but this is a negligible cost of few tenths of $.